# Java NIO: Multithreaded shared Selector

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, selector, nio

I want to implement non-blocking multiple TCP server - client communication with single selector using minimal threads(more than one). To utilize multi-tasking but optimize extra overhead because of each thread for each connection.

I want to use selector which must be shared within few threads. Main thread will listen for ready channels using select() call. Selected set of keys will be assigned to multiple threads to communicate in parallel.

Is this design possible? Given that:

> Selectors are themselves safe for use by multiple concurrent threads; their key sets, however, are not.

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. You should despatch each ready *key* to a thread, not try to share the entire selected-key set, which, as you quoted yourself, is not thread-safe.

Comment: What will happen if again an event comes for the same ready key, because main thread can again process select call.

Comment: Its `readyOps` will change.